# AgendaWeekView: Manipulate day split at midnight

Tags: fullcalendar

First of all thanks to Adam Shaw for his great Fullcalendar. I have a problem with the automatic day splitting, whenever an event belongs to two days. This works great in general, but is a problem in my specific use case:

I modified AgendaWeekView to show multiple rooms side by side, so each day has multiple rows:

```
 2011-01-01  |  2011-01-02
R1 | R2 | R3 | R1 | R2 | R3
```

I customize my events before giving them to Fullcalendar, mapping 2011-01-01 Room 1 at 2011-01-01, 2011-01-01 Room 2 at 2011-01-02, ... 2011-01-02 Room 1 at 2011-01-04 and so on.

Everything works fine with some changes to AgendaWeekView.render.

My only problem are dates starting e.g. at 2011-01-01 11pm: If they are longer than one hour, FullCalendar shows their end at the next day, which is - in my case - unfortunately 2011-01-01 Room 2. I tried to find the code splitting the event, hoping to add  the room number to the ending part's start date or something like this.

I don't really see this in the code. I hope somebody has advice where to start finding a solution.

Comment: What version of fullcalendar are you using?